# Magento Block Injction via module.xml Files

Tags: php, xml, magento

In a module I am writing I want to use using mymodule.xml to insert my own block after this block:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
```

which is nested within

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

as can be seen in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

I have tried many variants such as:

```
<reference name="content">
   <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="mymodule/folder_class" after="media" name="mymodule.folder.class" template="mymodule/folder/class.phtml" as="mymodule_folder_class"></block>
   </reference>
</reference>
```

and just

```
<reference name="product.info">
   <block type="mymodule/folder_class" after="media" name="mymodule.folder.class" template="mymodule/folder/class.phtml" as="mymodule_folder_class"></block>
</reference>
```

and

```
<reference name="product.info">
   <block type="mymodule/folder_class" after="media" name="mymodule.folder.class" template="mymodule/folder/class.phtml" as="mymodule_folder_class"></block>
</reference>
```

but I cant seem to find the correct combination.
the only one that renders my block is:

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="mymodule/folder_class" after="media" name="mymodule.folder.class" template="mymodule/folder/class.phtml" as="mymodule_folder_class"></block>
</reference>
```

but obviously it is not placed where I wanted it to be placed.

Comment: Answer below, but I also wanted to say this was a well asked question, and better than most of the unanswerable "it doesn't work?!?!???" sort of Layout questions we get around these parts.

Comment: Thanks @Alan
Your answer is very clear but changing `catalog/product/view.phtml`, while it might be a good idea if I was just a site owner, just feels wrong for me as an extension developer.
What if you where writing yet another another extension that needed to do the same thing (add your own block under the `catalog/product_view_media` block) ? won't this make our extensions mutually exclusive ? Is there no solution to this problem ? maybe getChildHtml should be overridden some how to allow additional blocks to be appended or prepended to existing ones based on the layout or config?

Comment: 1. If you're creating a module for redistribution and wide use then yes, altering an existing template file would be bad form (and wouldn't work across versions of Magento).  Unfortunately, I haven't seen a **good** solution for re-distributable modules that add-to/alter a layout. It all depends on who is going to be using your module. Because the layout's highly customizable, you're always going to at the mercy of what your module end-users have done or might do.

Comment: 2. As a module creator my general approach would be to provide end-users with block objects which they can add to their layout themselves, and offer them instructions on doing so. However, I create module's for tech savvy users.

Comment: 3. Rewriting catalog/product_view's or product.info.media's getChildHtml method to automatically insert your module at the right point is an option, but when you rewrite a class you've still made a **my module is the only module that can do this** claim.   Plus you're changing the a default behavior which will confuse anyone who's tech savvy that uses your layout.

Going Javascript only is another option.  Add a block to content that renders out some Javascript/AJAX code which will add your block to the right location on the page.

Hope that all helps, sorry I don't have a better answer.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks, I ended up with the javascript solution. I will combine configuration that will allow the site owner to decide where he wants to place the added UI. so he will be able to either leave the UI at its "default" location and do whatever changes he wants to his templates. or he can leave the templates alone and use this configuration to make the code inject the UI to its final location.
Maybe I will blog about it. (what is the appropriate way to close this Q? should I accept your answer ? or can I somehow accept a comment ?)

Comment: 4. I've been digging into the widget system a bit, and it seems like widgets are the intended way of letting store owners add something custom from a module to a specific block.  I'm not 100% sure of the how and why of it, but it might be worth investigating that route as well.

Comment: I was under the impression that widgets are intended for use only  within CMS pages, is this not the case ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of the content block up in `page.xml`, you'll see the following.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
```

By default, the block named content is a `core/text_list`, which translates to a `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List`.

The purpose of a `core/text_list` blocks is simple.  They **automatically render any blocks inserted into them**.  That's why you can insert a block into content successfully.

The block **you want** to insert into

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="mymodule/folder/class.phtml" ...
```

is a `catalog/product_view`, which translates to a  `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`, which ultimately inherits from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.  That makes it a Template block. Template blocks **do not** automatically render their children.  Template blocks will render a `phtml` file.  If that `phtml` contains a call to

```
$this->getChildHtml('block_name');
```

then the block with that specific name will be rendered.  If the `phtml` file contains a call to

```
$this->getChildHtml(); //no arguments
```

then **all** the child blocks will be rendered.

So, when you say

```
<reference name="product.info">
   <block type="mymodule/folder_class" after="media" name="mymodule.folder.class" template="mymodule/folder/class.phtml" as="mymodule_folder_class"></block>
</reference>
```

you're **inserting** a block of type `mymodule/folder_class` into the `product.info` block.  But, because `product.info` is a template block and not a text list block, it doesn't render the block you inserted.  You'll need to add a custom `catalog/product/view.phtml` template to your theme (by copying the base template), and then at the bottom of `view.phtml`, add

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mymodule.folder.class');?>
```

Comment: Instead of copying the base template, you could use the local.xml [trick](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/using-local-xml-for-overriding-or-updating-xml-structure/) to override the layouts.

Comment: @yvoyer, are you suggesting getting a reference to product.info an setting its template?  Or something else?   Also, epeleg mentioned wanting to do this from a custom module, so changing local.xml might not be the best choice.

Comment: I was just pointing out that he could override his layout in the local.xml, just in case he did not know about it. But you are right that it might not be the best choice for now.

Comment: THANK YOU for this explanation!  I have been tearing my hair out for a couple of hours wondering why my block wasn't showing up when a similar syntax worked in another place.  Is there a comprehensive list of block types out there anywhere for reference?  Otherwise, I guess I have to scan the core code to see what it does and how it differs from other block types....quite annoying!

Comment: @BrianVPS: My Book "No Frills Magento Layout" has a full list of all the block classes that ship with Magento 1.4.2, which you can then derive types from.  (http://www.pulsestorm.net/magento-layout/).  Also, related, my free Developer Manual extension, which lets you input any block type and get a list of methods for http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/alanstorm/extension/5577/developer_manual.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the block in the `catalog/product/view action`, I believe you should put it like this, else replace `catalog_product_view` by the desired action or `default` for any actions.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/folder_class" after="media" name="mymodule.folder.class" template="mymodule/folder/class.phtml" as="mymodule_folder_class">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: Not right.  This would apply the layout change to pages **only** when the view action in the product controller in the catalog module was called (catalog_product_view).  The problem epeleg is trying to solve is adding a layout block to a **specific** location in the layout that's not a part of the content block.

Comment: Well actually I did do all my changes inside `<catalog_product_view>`.
@alan am I to understand from your comment that I can reference a block by name without nesting it inside such a handle (I hope I am getting all the terminology right - catalog_product_view is a handle, right?) and it will be applied to any block with the referenced name?

Comment: @epeleg: when you're adding code to the various layout.xml files they do need to be nested inside of a handle (you have those terms right).  My comment was just pointing out you already seemed to know where to put your block, and that your problem was getting it to render.